# Complicated index models and Boolean algebras/ Shelah/ Unclear step in the proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, set-theory, boolean-algebra, natural-numbers

[Here](http://shelah.logic.at/nonstructure/VII.pdf) on the page $10$ in the $5$th line (the proof of lemma $1.10$), Shelah defines $n_*$ as $\omega$: $$n_*=\omega,$$
and then he continues:
be such that $n_*\geq\text{max}\{n(0),...,n(m-1)\}<\omega.$

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper you are quoting does not say

> $n_*\geq\{\text{max}(n(0),...,n(m-1)\}<\omega.$

it says

> $n_*\geq\text{max}\{n(0),...,n(m-1)\}<\omega.$

and certainly if the middle $<\omega$, it is going to be less than $n_\ast=\omega$.

I can't speak for the rest of the paper, but I don't see anything particularly odd about the line.

Comment: Fine, and what are $n$ and $m$ there?

Comment: @user122424 The $n(..)$'s are defined right after the last $\{1.4\}$ marker on page 9.

Comment: @NotMike But **how** is $n(...$ a function. It appears to me that it is a number $<\omega$ ...But on the page $10$ 5th line they put arguments to it: $n(0),...,n(m-1)$

Comment: @user122424 by induction/recursion